# Build Boost.Python with Faber

Tags: python, boost, build, boost-python

When I try to run Faber I get the following error message every time I try to run it.
Can anyone help me?

```
D:\boost_1_74_0\libs\python> faber
Error: C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\faber-0.4.2-py3.8.egg\faber\project.py:52: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\username/.faber'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to run as administrator under Windows environment

Comment: seems more like a comment